# Ember-data: this.store.find() range of entries?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to figure out a way to retrieve a subset of items based on a range of sequential IDs. In other words, I need to return entries 52-64 as my model. Can I do this with `this.store.find()`? I can't seem to find anything the documentation about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the objects already loaded in the `store` or are you making an AJAX call to the server?

Comment: There will be an AJAX call.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/#toc_querying-for-records

Comment: Close. But, I think it got me to where I needed to go. You can include an array as the value of the property in the second parameter of the `find()` function. Like: `this.store.find('entry', {id: [1, 2, 3, 4]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, while I don't know whether you can truly find a "range" with Ember Data, you can pass multiple `ids` or other attribute properties as an array, which will make a request for all of the items. E.g. `this.store.find('entry', {id: [1, 2, 3, 4]})`. Therfore, you can just build an array of values that represent your range, and it should work. Something like:

```
model: function(from, to){
    var items = [];
    for(i = from; i <= to; i++){
        items.push(i);
    }

    return this.store.find('Item', {id: items})
}
```